# How do I shrink the child view like in the GridView

Tags: dart, flutter

Does any one know how to accomplish the shrinking of the child view in Flutter as show here in the first picture. I used a gridView which does the job very well.

On the second picture I used a row, I tried it with Container and Constrains but it didn't worked out very well. ;D

[image: GridView]

```
 return new GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,

    children: widget.foodItems.map((FoodViewModel food){
        return new FoodTile(
            name: food.name,
            icon: food.icon
            , onPressed: (bool state) {
              food.isSelected = state;
              widget?.onFoodItemTaped(food, state);
            },
        );
    }).toList(),
);
```

[image: RowView]
Here the row-code without any constrains
    return new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),

```
      child:new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            child: new FoodTile(name: "Tile one", onPressed:(bool state){}),
          ),
          new Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            child: new FoodTile(name: "Tile two", onPressed:(bool state){}),
          ),
          new Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            child: new FoodTile(name: "Tile three", onPressed:(bool state){}),
          )

        ],
      )
    ));
```

[Complete source code to the tile](https://github.com/swissonid/fling/blob/expansion-panel/lib/component/food_tile.dart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the instances of `FoodTile` in a `Flexible` or `Expanded` so that the `Row` will apply a flexible layout model to them and space them evenly.

Comment: Thx that did it. But I had to wrap it to in LayoutBuild to keep the square. `new Expanded(child: new LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context,  BoxConstraints constraints){
                return new Container(
                  constraints: new BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: constraints.maxWidth, height: constraints.maxWidth),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: new FoodTile(name:"hallo 2",onPressed: (bool state){}),
                );
              })),`

Comment: Thx that did it. But I had to wrap it to in LayoutBuild to keep the square.

Answer (score -1):

Just if someone is wondering how the end result looks. I'm still a bit unhappy with the "LayoutBuilder-Solution" but it works for me right know.

```
return new SingleChildScrollView(
    child: new Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),

      child: new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(child: new LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context,  BoxConstraints constraints){
            return new Container(
              constraints: new BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: constraints.maxWidth, height: constraints.maxWidth),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
              child: new FoodTile(name:"hallo",onPressed: (bool state){}),
            );
          })),
          new Expanded(child: new LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context,  BoxConstraints constraints){
            return new Container(
              constraints: new BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: constraints.maxWidth, height: constraints.maxWidth),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
              child: new FoodTile(name:"hallo 2",onPressed: (bool state){}),
            );
          })),
          new Expanded(child: new LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context,  BoxConstraints constraints){
            return new Container(
              constraints: new BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: constraints.maxWidth, height: constraints.maxWidth),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
              child: new FoodTile(name:"hallo 3",onPressed: (bool state){}),
            );
          })),
        ],
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: You could try refactoring our the Expanded Container into a function. Something like: https://gist.github.com/sethladd/df690b2eb5923a5699aabbdbb869b1b9#file-updated2-dart